# cakephp delete threaded records

Tags: cakephp

I have implemented comments functionality in one of my sites using CakePHP and it's `find('threaded')` feature.

When I delete a parent comment, I want all it's child comments (n-level children) to get deleted too, using CakePHP model's delete method.

Say, following is the case:

id = 5   parent_id = 0;
id = 6   parent_id = 5;
id = 7   parent_id = 5;
id = 8   parent_id = **7**;

And I do:

```
$this->Comment->id = 5;
$this->Comment->delete();
```

I want records with comment id = 5, 6, 7, 8 to get deleted.

Please advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested the following code, but I would do something like this:

```
<?php
class Comment extends AppModel {
    public function afterDelete() {
        $this->deleteChildren($this->id);
    }

    private function deleteChildren($parentId) {
        $children = $this->findByParentId($parentId);
        if (!empty($children)) {
            foreach ($children as $child) {
                $this->deleteChildren($child['Comment']['id']);
                $this->delete($child['Comment']['id']);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It worked with few corrections as posted in my answer below. Thanks a ton greew.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the way to go... I'm not sure if you've defined this relationship in your model file, but if so: you could simply set `'dependent' => true` in your association definition and deleting child elements will be done automagically.

Answer (score 0):

Minor corrections in @greew's answer above and it worked like below for me:

```
public function afterDelete() {
     $this->__deleteChildren($this->id);
}

private function __deleteChildren($parentId) {
   $children = $this->findAllByParentId($parentId);
   if (!empty($children)) {
        foreach ($children as $child) {
           $this->delete($child['Comment']['id']);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot greew!

Comment: Yes, of course. No need to call __deleteChildren in the foreach loop. It is automatically done, when calling the delete method. I'm glad it worked, though Joep does have a point about the 'dependent' setting. It should work also, and actually is the CakePHP way of doing it.